# Java exception handling get console error message

Tags: java, exception

I want to get error message using java when exception are generated.

now I have java code with following scenario:

```
method first(){

     try{
        second();
     }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error:> "+e)
     }

}
```

---

```
method second(){

     try{
       my code
     }catch(Exception e){
        throw new Exception("Exception generate in second method",e);
     }

}
```

now when the first method execute then I get only "Exception generate in second method" message but there is some other message printed on console by java so how to get that console error message.

Note: I have already try with e.getMessage(); and e.printStackTrace();

Comment: Where do you want the stack to be printed ? In first or second ?

Comment: Can you add the message to your question?

Comment: Here you are getting "Exception generate in second method" only because you are catching exception in second() method and hence catch block in first() method will never be executed.

Comment: @ShoaibChikate The catch block in the second method throws an exception so it will be propagated to the calling method i;e first method. Ideally the catch block of the first method should run

Comment: @underdog: My mistake, I didn't see that my apology.

Answer (score 1):

Every exception has a cause that you can get with `getCause()`. You can go recursively down them until you get to the root cause. Here is your example with a utility that dumps the exception with all its causes like the console does.

```
private void first() {
    try  {
        second();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e("CATCH", getExceptionDump(ex));
    }
}

private void second() {
    try {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("We don't do this.");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Exception in second()", ex);
    }
}

private String getExceptionDump(Exception ex) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (Throwable cause = ex; cause != null; cause = cause.getCause()) {
        if (result.length() > 0)
            result.append("Caused by: ");
        result.append(cause.getClass().getName());
        result.append(": ");
        result.append(cause.getMessage());
        result.append("\n");
        for (StackTraceElement element: cause.getStackTrace()) {
            result.append("\tat ");
            result.append(element.getMethodName());
            result.append("(");
            result.append(element.getFileName());
            result.append(":");
            result.append(element.getLineNumber());
            result.append(")\n");
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The message in the Exception constructor argument is not printed in the exception detail. 
You can simply use this code to print the message :

```
method first(){

     try{
        second();
     }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error:> "+e.getMessage())
     }

}
```

Hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

**Why you cannot use print stack trace ?**

Because `A throwable contains a snapshot of the execution stack of its thread at the time it was created.` (see [Throwable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html))

It implies that, if you want to print the stack trace you need to use the `printStackTrace()` method BUT in your second method !

```
method second(){
  try {
    my code
  } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new Exception("Exception generate in second method",e);
  }
 }
```

Or using a the tricky method `setStackTrace` and using the `printStackTrace()` in first

```
method second(){
  try {
    my code
  } catch(Exception e) {
    Exception ex = new Exception("Exception generate in second method",e);
    ex.setStackTrace(e);
    throw ex;
  }
 }
```

---

```
method first(){

 try {
   second();
 } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print the cause of the exception you get. Try this:

```
method first(){

     try{
        second();
     }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error:> "+e);
        if (e.getCause() != null) {
            System.out.println("Cause:> " + e.getCause());
        }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the console message you want to achieve:

```
Error:> java.lang.Exception: Exception generate in second method
```

Try this code, when the catch block of the second method throws an exception the second method should declare it as throws or put a nested try catch within the catch block.

The exception is propagated to the first() method which is handled by its catch block.

```
 public class Test {

        public void first() {

            try {
                second();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error:> " + e);
            }

        }

        public void second() throws Exception {

            try {
                throw new Exception();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new Exception("Exception generate in second method", e);
            }
        }

        public static void main(String ars[]) {

            Test test = new Test();

            test.first();

        }
    }
```